# How to get keySet() and size() for entire GridGain cluster?

Tags: caching, cluster-computing, gridgain

`GridCache.keySet()`, `.primarySize()`, and `.size()` only return information for that node.

How do I get these information but for the whole cluster?

[Scanning the entire cluster](http://atlassian.gridgain.com/wiki/display/GG60/SQL%2C+Scan%2C+And+Full+Text+Queries) "works", but all I need is the keys or the count, not the values.

The problem is SQL query works if I want to find based on an indexed field, but I can't find based on the grid cache entry key itself.

My workaround that works but far from elegant and performant is:

```
Set<String> ruleIds = FluentIterable.from(cache.queries().createSqlFieldsQuery("SELECT property FROM YagoRule").execute().get())
        .<String>transform((it) -> (String) it.iterator().next()).toSet();
```

This requires the key is the same as one of the field, and the field need to be indexed for performance reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next release of GridGain (6.2.0) will have `globalSize()` and `globalPrimarySize()` methods which will ask the cluster for the sizes.

For now you can use the following code:

```
// Only grab nodes on which cache "mycache" is started.
GridCompute compute = grid.forCache("mycache").compute();

Collection<Integer> res = compute.broadcast(
    // This code will execute on every caching node.
    new GridCallable<Integer>() {
         @Override public Integer call() {
             return grid.cache("mycache").size();
         }
    }
).get();

int sum = 0;

for (Integer i : res)
    sum += i;
```

Comment: What about `globalKeySet()` ? BTW I think your snippet above would be sum of all sizes (disregarding intersections), not the total size of all entries. i.e. node1 has keys A, B, C while node2 has keys B, C, D. your snippet would return 6 although the expected size would be 4. But if this is fixed in 6.2.0 then I'm happy :)

Comment: @HendyIrawan Instead of "size()" method, you should use "primarySize()" method in the above example, and it will return exactly the size you are asking about.